# enum usage for bitwise and in GLSL

Tags: c++, glsl

Ok, this is probably an easy one for the pro's out there. I want to use an enum in GLSL in order to make an if bitwise and check on it, like in c++.

Pseudo C++ code:

```
enum PolyFlags
{
    Invisible       = 0x00000001,   
    Masked          = 0x00000002,   
    Translucent     = 0x00000004,
    ...
};

...

if ( Flag & Masked)
    Alphathreshold = 0.5;
```

But I am already lost at the beginning because it fails already compiling with:

**'enum' : Reserved word**

I read that enum's in GLSL are supposed to work as well as the bitwise and, but I can't find a working example.

So, is it actually working/supported and if so, how? I tried already with different #version in the shader, but no luck so far.

Comment: does your compiler points a specific line? Seems to me that a semicolon is missing at the end of your enum definition.

Comment: no, the ; is there, that's not it. I just forgot it in my example code :)

Comment: I think it would be worth putting together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I.e. provide us with a short, but complete program and without the `...`.

Comment: All I want to know is a short explanation or better, an example, about how to use "enum" in a shader correctly, preferably but not necessarily in combination with a "bitwise and". If I would know what to write, I wouldn't ask, right now it's a question of pure theoretical nature because I didn't find anything useful here or in the web except it being mentioned to be supported, I don't have a program for this yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OpenGL Shading Language does not have enumeration types. However, they are reserved keywords, which is why you got that particular compiler error.

C enums are really just syntactic sugar for a value (C++ gives them some type-safety, with `enum class`es having much more). So you can emulate them in a number of ways. Perhaps the most traditional (and dangerous) is with #defines:

```
#define Invisible    0x00000001u
#define Masked       0x00000002u
#define Translucent  0x00000004u
```

A more reasonable way is to declare compile-time `const` qualified global variables. Any GLSL compiler worth using will optimize them away to nothingness, so they won't take up any more resources than the `#define`. And it won't have any of the drawbacks of the `#define`.

```
const uint Invisible    = 0x00000001u;
const uint Masked       = 0x00000002u;
const uint Translucent  = 0x00000004u;
```

Obviously, you need to be using a version of GLSL that supports unsigned integers and bitwise operations (aka: GLSL 1.30+, or GLSL ES 3.00+).

Comment: Then I only wonder why some sources claim that enums are actually supported. Thanks for the detailed answer and the optimization hint.

Comment: well, one thing yet maybe :) In C++ I can do if (PolyFlags & Masked),but in GLSL this raises ERROR: 0:101: '' : boolean expression expected  - what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: oh nvm, I think I know, "if" in GLSL always expects a comparison.

Comment: @Gnampf I don't know anything about GLSL, but the C++ `if (flag & mask)` uses an implicit conversion from `uint` to `bool`. You can make this explicit by writing `if ( 0 != (PolyFlags & Masked))` which should fix your problem in GLSL.

Comment: @Gnampf it doesn't expect a comparison, it expects a boolean expression. So an explicit conversion like `if(bool(PolyFlags & Masked))` will also work.